# How to count the number of words per line in text file using RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there a way to count the number of word occurrences for each line of an RDD and not the complete RDD using map and reduce?

For example, if an RDD[String] contains these two lines:

> Let's have some fun.
>
> To have fun you don't need any plans.

then the output should be like a map containing the key value pairs:

> ("Let's",1)
>   ("have",1)
>   ("some",1)
>   ("fun",1)
>
> ("To",1)
> ("have",1)
> ("fun",1)
> ("you",1)
> ("don't",1)
> ("need",1)
> ("plans",1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my understanding you can do the following
You said that you have `RDD[String]` data

```
val data = Seq("Let's have some fun.",
  "To have fun you don't need any plans.")
val rddData = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
```

You can apply `flatMap` to `split` the `lines` and create `(word, 1)` `tuples` in `map` function

```
val output = rddData.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1))
```

that should give you your desired output

```
output.foreach(println)
```

To have occurances by line you should do the following

```
val output = rddData.map(_.split(" ").map((_, 1)).groupBy(_._1)
  .map { case (group: String, traversable) => traversable.reduce{(a,b) => (a._1, a._2 + b._2)} }.toList).flatMap(tuple => tuple)
```

Comment: Your solution is more concise but you don't count the occurences by line

Comment: @KireetBhat, If it helped you please upvote too. Thanks

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Can you please post pyspark equavalent code for word count each line

Answer (score 5):

Please, don't use RDD API if you've just started using Spark and no one told you to use it. There's so much nicer and often more efficient Spark SQL API to do this and many other distributed computations over large datasets in Spark.

Using RDD API is like using assembler for something you can use Scala (or other higher-level programming language) for. It's certainly too much to think about when starting your journey into Spark that I'd personally recommend the higher-level API of Spark SQL with DataFrames and Datasets in the first place.

---

Given the input:

```
$ cat input.txt
Let's have some fun.

To have fun you don't need any plans.
```

and that you were to use Dataset API, you could do the following:

```
val lines = spark.read.text("input.txt").withColumnRenamed("value", "line")
val wordsPerLine = lines.withColumn("words", explode(split($"line", "\\s+")))
scala> wordsPerLine.show(false)
+-------------------------------------+------+
|line                                 |words |
+-------------------------------------+------+
|Let's have some fun.                 |Let's |
|Let's have some fun.                 |have  |
|Let's have some fun.                 |some  |
|Let's have some fun.                 |fun.  |
|                                     |      |
|To have fun you don't need any plans.|To    |
|To have fun you don't need any plans.|have  |
|To have fun you don't need any plans.|fun   |
|To have fun you don't need any plans.|you   |
|To have fun you don't need any plans.|don't |
|To have fun you don't need any plans.|need  |
|To have fun you don't need any plans.|any   |
|To have fun you don't need any plans.|plans.|
+-------------------------------------+------+

scala> wordsPerLine.
  groupBy("line", "words").
  count.
  withColumn("word_count", struct($"words", $"count")).
  select("line", "word_count").
  groupBy("line").
  agg(collect_set("word_count")).
  show(truncate = false)
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|line                                 |collect_set(word_count)                                                       |
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|To have fun you don't need any plans.|[[fun,1], [you,1], [don't,1], [have,1], [plans.,1], [any,1], [need,1], [To,1]]|
|Let's have some fun.                 |[[have,1], [fun.,1], [Let's,1], [some,1]]                                     |
|                                     |[[,1]]                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Done. *Simple, isn't it?*

See [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) object (for `explode` and `struct` functions).

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to transform a line into a Map(word, count). So you can define a function count word by line :

```
def wordsCount(line: String):Map[String,Int] = {
 line.split(" ").map(v => (v,1)).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.size)
}
```

then just apply it to your RDD[String]:

```
val lines:RDD[String] = ...
val wordsByLineRDD:RDD[Map[String,Int]] = lines.map(wordsCount)
// this should give you a Map per line with count of each word
wordsByLineRDD.take(2)
// Something like
// Array(Map(some -> 1, have -> 1, Let's -> 1, fun. -> 1), Map(any -> 1, have -> 1, don't -> 1, you -> 1, need -> 1, fun -> 1, To -> 1, plans. -> 1))
```

Comment: Can you please  put the pyspark equvalent code for above problem i.e word count for each line

Comment: @Nandu check the last post, someone provides a pyspark solution

Answer (score 2):

Although it is an old question; I was looking for an answer to this in pySpark. Finally managed like the below.

```
file_ = cont_.parallelize (
    ["shots are shots that are shots with more big shots by big people",
     "people comes in all shapes and sizes, as people are idoits of the idiots",
     "i know what i am writing is nonsense, but i don't care because i am doing this to test my spark program",
     "my spark is a current spark, that spark in my eyes."]
)

file_ \
.map(lambda x : [((x, i), 1) for i in x.split()]) \
.flatMap(lambda x : x) \
.reduceByKey(lambda x, y : x + y) \
.sortByKey(False) \
.map(lambda x : (x[0][1], x[1])) \
.collect()
```

Comment: This question is tagged `scala` so a `pySpark` solution is out of place. Please delete it.

Comment: I had this problem and while searching this is the only relevant page I could find. I see it is tagged for Scala, but in the main question it was mentioned so. I submitted the answer so that anyone else probably searching for the similar solution might find it useful. If you feel the answer is wrong, do let me know and I shall correct it. And if you still feel it is completely unnecessary, then I would delete it!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your rdd like this

```
val data = Seq("Let's have some fun.",
  "To have fun you don't need any plans.")
val rddData = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
```

Then simply apply `flapMap` and then `map`

```
val res = rddData.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1))
```

Expected Output

```
res.take(100)
res4: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((Let's,1), (have,1), (some,1), (fun.,1), (To,1), (have,1), (fun,1), (you,1), (don't,1), (need,1), (any,1), (plans.,1))
```